# Javascript equivalent to python __init__.py

Tags: javascript, package

In python, in order to expose top-level functionality in a package, one would create an `__init__.py`

```
#__init__.py
from .implmentation import impl_function

def exposed_fn():

  """call impl_function
```

Which would expose `exposed_fn` as the main function to use when importing a directory (package). What's the equivlalent of this in javascript's `require`?

Obviously you can do the following.

```
//init.js?
var impl_function = require('./implmentation.js').impl_function;

var exposed_fn = function () {//call impl_function ...};

//Will expose `exposed_fn` when requiring this file.
module.exports = {
  exposed_fn: exposed_fn
}

//How to expose `expose_fn` when requiring a this folder?????
```

Is there an equivalent? All searches so far haven't proved fruitful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using an `index.js` file in the same manner seems to work. If you export objects from an `index.js` file they can be accessible at the folder level.

Comment: Is there an equivalent to `__all__=['some_module']` to define the namespace in `index.js` the same way you'd do with `__init__.py`?